# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have this code for scraping facebook using beautifulsoup but getting an error in the 'str' part. i've read that python reads this like a variable which should be a function. but I still don't understand the point.

```
from  selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import re
import json
import pandas as pd
from account_credentails import username, password

class Post_Scraper:
    """
    Post_Scraper class allows to scrape Facebook Posts based on search queries.
    """
    LOGIN_URL = "https://www.facebook.com"
    REACTIONS_NAMES = ['Like', 'Angry', 'Love', 'Haha', 'Sad','Care', 'Wow']

    def __init__(self, driver_path, posts_url) -> None:
        driver_path=driver_path('C:\Program Files\Python 3.9\chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path=driver_path)
        self.posts_url = posts_url.replace("www", "mbasic")


    def login(self, username, password) -> None:
        """
        Login to a Facebook Account.

        Args:
            username ('str'))
                Facebook account username/email
            password ('str')
                Facebook account password    
        """
        self.driver.get(self.LOGIN_URL)
        time.sleep(2)
        email_ = self.driver.find_element_by_name("email")
        pass_ = self.driver.find_element_by_name("pass")
        email_.send_keys(username)
        time.sleep(1)
        pass_.send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(2)
        email_.submit()
        time.sleep(10)
```

I am getting an error like this 'TypeError: 'str' object is not callable', so what should i do?

Comment: Always provide the full traceback of the error.

Comment: At what line you are getting the error ?

Comment: please let me know if 'del str' works - I'm quite curious about this issue now

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to figure out if you share **which line** triggered this, but according to [this thread about the same error message](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/very-basic-website-scraper-str-object-is-not-callable.984485/),

> ...suggests that this can happen if you've defined a variable called str before running your script. Then python thinks you are referring to this variable and wonders why you are trying to call a variable

so the error might go away if you add

```py
str = None # in case str HASN'T been defined...
del str
```

somewhere before whichever line caused the error.